# Why does library("dplyr") in .Rprofile behave differently

Tags: r, macos, rprofile

I'm mystified as to why a statement in .Rprofile has such a different effect from regular code.  Specifically, I want to include `library("dplyr")` in .Rprofile to have it always loaded in OSX.

The effect of an .Rprofile as follows:

```
library("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
```

is:

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:

    intersect, setdiff, union

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

If .Rprofile only has `library("lubridate")`, the effect of `library("dplyr")` as the first statement in an R session is:

```
Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter

The following objects are masked from ‘package:lubridate’:

    intersect, setdiff, union

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

As a result dplyr commands like `filter` do not work properly.  Why is this?

Comment: Read ?Startup. Stats package isn't loaded at that point.

Comment: Ie http://stackoverflow.com/q/26935095/324364