# Select or delete duplicate records based on a rule

Tags: r

I have the following dataset that contains `id`, `sex`, and a numeric variable, `xvar`.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5)
sex <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2)
xvar <- c(10,11,10,12,9,9.1,10,10.4,3,2.9,4,11,11.1)
df <- data.frame(id,sex,xvar)
```

For each `id`, I want to check the min and max of `xvar`. If `1.05*min(xvar) >=  max(xvar)` then I need to keep the records. Otherwise, delete them.

For example, if `id` is 1, `min(xvar)=10` and `max(xvar)=12`. Also, `1.05*10 < 12` ... then 
delete the records for the `id` of 1.

Another example is when `id` is 5. So `min(xvar)=11`, `max(xvar)=11.1`, and `1.05*11 > 11.1`. Keep the records where `id` is 5.

Comment: `df[as.logical(with(df, ave(xvar, id, FUN = function(x) 1.05*min(x) >= max(x)))), ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `data.table` as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
output <- df[ , if (1.05 * min(xvar) >= max(xvar)) .SD, by = id]
```

`by = id` (invisibly) partitions the table into a set of `length(unique(id))` `data.tables`, one for each value of `id`; within each of these, we find the range of `xvar` and return the entire table (i.e., `.SD`) only if your condition is met.

Some more about `.SD`:

First, notice that `.SD` is in the `j` argument, which is usually a `list` of columns or a list of expressions involving columns, so `.SD` must also be a `list`. What `list` is it? It's the `list` of *all* columns in the `data.table`.

(See `?data.table` for more advanced usage, e.g., the `.SDcols` argument which allows us to specify a subset of columns to be denoted by `.SD`)

Comment: Thank you. by the way, what does .SD do?

Comment: @user9292 see edit. I'm with you that it's a bit nebulous at first; let me know whether I've explained it well enough.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelChirico. That's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in dplyr, too:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df%>%
  group_by(id)%>%
  dplyr::filter(1.05*min(xvar)>=max(xvar))
```

group_by creates 'blocks' of data to iterate through at a time, the filter code is then applied to each of these blocks in turn.

Comment: why use `dplyr::filter` (as opposed to just `filter`)? Is it overloaded?

Comment: I added this to prevent any confusion with the filter function from the stats package (which would run, but not give the correct solution). I've noted some users have had this issue before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935095/r-dplyr-filter-not-masking-base-filter)